# Que signifie exactement « pour que » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: expressions

> Je ne sais pas. Mais **pour que** quelqu'un de haut placé fasse détruire une pièce à conviction, ça devait être très important.

En général, « pour que » sert à introduire un but, et il s'agit donc de l'avenir plutôt que du passé. Mais dans ce cas précis, cela semble indiquer « **compte tenu d**'une chose qui s'est **déjà** passée ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« **Pour que** » indique ici la conséquence, pas le but. La proposition principale « **ça devait être très important** » indique la raison qui explique ce qui est exprimé dans la subordonnée : « **pour que quelqu'un de haut placé fasse détruire une pièce à conviction** ».

La principale ne met pas en doute la destruction, une pièce à conviction a donc bien été détruite. Le verbe « **devoir** » exprime seulement une incertitude sur le niveau d'importance de la pièce. La subordonnée utilise le subjonctif car bien que la destruction ait eu lieu, elle est quand même imaginée. On ne sait pas exactement ce qui s'est passé. L'indicatif aurait été indiqué si la subordonnée avait décrit un fait avéré : « **Puisque quelqu'un de haut placé a fait détruire une pièce à conviction, ça devait être très important** ».

Comment: I would be tempted to use the past tense and say "*pour que quelqu'un de haut placé **ait fait** détruire une pièce à conviction*". I wonder why the use of the past tense is not allowed here? Merci.

Comment: The past subjunctive tense like in your example is certainly possible too. The present is used to describe any destruction of this kind, the past to describe what happened precisely in that specific case.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the present tense refers to a general statement. I never imagined that the present vs past tense would lead to such an interesting difference. Merci !

Comment: Is this specific usage of « pour que » quite common in both everyday speech and writing? Merci.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is very common but it is certainly understood without diificulty by native speakers and probably not perceived as a specific usage. E.g. *Pour qu'il se fasse flasher, il devait rouler très vite !*

Answer (score 0):

Tu as raison en disant que ça semble indiquer 'compte tenu de'.

> Pour que, pour... que + indicatif, subjonctif ou conditionnel.

Donc 'pour que' peut être subjonctif ou conditionnel.  Dans ce sens-ci, il me semble que 'pour que' soit conditionnel.

Comment: Hi. Am I correct in assuming that this sentence means that "someone **tried in vain** to destroy the evidence" rather than "someone **did actually succeed** in destroying the evidence"? Because in order to express the idea of the latter, you need to say "*pour que quelqu'un de haut placé **ait fait détruire** une pièce à conviction*"? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA, no that's the other way around. If someone tried in vain, the sentence would have been *de haut placé ait essayé de faire détruire* and/or end with *il aurait fallu que ce soit (fût) très important* or even *il eût fallu que c'eût été très important* ;-)